# Bigquery finding text in a column based on another table

Tags: arrays, regex, select, google-bigquery, match

I would like to return all blocklist terms contained in the product description

```
with blocklist as (

    select 'instagram' as blocklist union all
    select 'facebook' as blocklist union all
    select 'whatsapp web'
),
products as (

    select 'seller1' as seller, 'Tenis Nike 43 call me on instagram or facebook'    as product union all
    select 'seller1' as seller, 'TV 42 sansung link whatsapp WEB or INSTAGRAM'      as product union all
    select 'seller2' as seller, 'TV 42 sansung link'                                as product

)
select
     seller
    ,product
    ,blocklists
from
    ?
```

Where would the result be this

| seller | product | blocklists |
| --- | --- | --- |
| seller 1 | Tenis Nike 43 call me on instagram or facebook | instagram,facebook |
| seller 1 | TV 42 sansung link whatsapp WEB | whatsapp web,instagram |
| seller 2 | TV 42 sansung link | null |

Do i need to transform blocklist into array , use regex on select ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works on your example:

```
with blocklist as (
    select 'instagran' as blocklist union all
    select 'facebook' as blocklist union all
    select 'whatsapp web'
),
products as (
    select 'seller1' as seller, 'Tenis Nike 43 call me on instagram or facebook'    as product union all
    select 'seller1' as seller, 'TV 42 sansung link whatsapp WEB or INSTAGRAM'      as product union all
    select 'seller2' as seller, 'TV 42 sansung link'                                as product
)
select p.*,
       (select array_agg(bl.blocklist)
        from blocklist bl
        where lower(p.product) like concat('%', lower(bl.blocklist), '%')
     )
from products p
```

Comment: hello Gordon! tks a lot . Is it possible to transform this array into a comma-separated string?

Comment: i change array_agg for string_agg and works! tks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Consider also below approach

```
select p.*,
  lower(array_to_string(regexp_extract_all(product, r'(?i)' || list), ', ')) blocklists
from products p, (select string_agg(b.blocklist, '|') list from blocklist b)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

You can play with it by yourself using below

```
with blocklist as (
  select 'instagram' as blocklist union all
  select 'facebook' as blocklist union all
  select 'whatsapp web'
), products as (
  select 'seller1' as seller, 'Tenis Nike 43 call me on instagram or facebook'    as product union all
  select 'seller1' as seller, 'TV 42 sansung link whatsapp WEB or INSTAGRAM'      as product union all
  select 'seller2' as seller, 'TV 42 sansung link'                                as product
)
select p.*,
  lower(array_to_string(regexp_extract_all(product, r'(?i)' || list), ', ')) blocklists
from products p, (select string_agg(b.blocklist, '|') list from blocklist b)
```

Comment: Im try to use regexp_extract_all but bigquery show me:
Cannot parse regular expression: no argument for repetition operator: ?

Comment: check back in few minutes - will add test example to my answer for you to play with

Comment: added example to my answer!

Comment: tks for attention.
My table products has more than 1 b of  billion of rows. I would like to avoid the Cartezian (product x blocklist), cause Bigquery sent me the msg "Cannot query rows larger than 100MB limit".
Is there a way to do this match line-by-line? ex:
select 
   p.*,
   p.product => in list or array of blocklists
from products p